# C++ Builder built COM module fails to link because __stdcall _com_issue_error(long) is unresolved

Tags: com, c++builder

I have a module that uses `WMI` to get the `smbios` data.  `WMI` though `COM` interface, nothing fancy.  It compiled fine but when I use the static library created in the application the link fails with:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__stdcall
> _com_issue_error(long)' referenced from Libname|modname

This is supposed to be in the `comsupp` or `comsuppw` library however, `#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw");` results with an error that it can't find `COMSUPPW.LIB` (I've tried the different naming as well: comsupp, comsuppwd)

I read that this library is only included with Visual Studio but I used C++ builder to build it.  It doesn't seem like it would build something it can't link to.  Is there some other library to use in C++ Builder to solve the problem?

FWIW this is the includes dealing with com:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <oaidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")
```

**EDIT:**

I converted the Microsoft `comsupp` libraries to OMF/ELF but same issue so it must not be in that library.

I see the function is in `comutil.cpp` included with c++ builder, however there isn't a `comutil` library to link with, is there another library that should be used?  I `#include <comutil.cpp>` in the main .cpp module (the one with `_tWinMain`) but it didn't change anything, perhaps a namespace issue...

However I tried just adding the code below to my main module but that gives

> ISO C++ 17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications

```
#include <comdef.h>

#pragma option push -b -a8 -pc -A- /*P_O_Push*/

void __stdcall _com_raise_error(HRESULT hr, IErrorInfo* perrinfo) throw (_com_error)
{
    throw _com_error(hr, perrinfo);
}

void __stdcall _com_issue_error(HRESULT hr) throw(_com_error)
{
    throw _com_error(hr);
}

void _stdcall _com_issue_errorex(HRESULT hr, IUnknown*, REFIID) throw(_com_error){
    throw _com_error(hr);
}

#pragma option pop /*P_O_Pop*/
```

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: "*ISO C++ 17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications*" - simply remove the `throw (_com_error)` specifier from the end of each function declaration (or, replace them with `noexcept(false)`). [Dynamic exception specifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) were deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17. They have been replaced with the [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you remove it you get an error that it's missing the throw, if you don't include the `comdef.h` then you get use of undeclared identifier `_com_error`   Also it complains about needing `(` after throw.  But yet if I include` comutil.cpp` in the name space no errors and no errors including `comdef.h`  so it's like it's stuck in a catch 22?

Comment: To get around it for now I just created the function with `throw("ComError");` but that is just a patch.  There has to be something I'm missing or they have a catch 22 bug they should fix?

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs related to the library:

- [comdef.h is not valid C++17](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24003), which should be fixed in C++ Builder 10.3.2. However the below code fixes it as well.
- [Could not use comutil.h in any project](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33261), which you can fix by creating `_com_issue_error` by yourself.

  ```
  #pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

  #pragma clang diagnostic push
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wkeyword-macro"

  // This is needed because comdef.h in C++ Builder 10.3 is not valid C++17
  #if __cplusplus >= 201703L
        #define throw(...)
  #endif

  #define _WIN32_DCOM
  #include <comdef.h>
  #include <Wbemidl.h>

  #if __cplusplus >= 201703L
        #undef throw
  #endif

  #pragma clang diagnostic pop

  // Implemented here because comsupp.lib is missing from C++ Builder 10.1.
  void __stdcall _com_issue_error(HRESULT hr)
  {
        throw _com_error(hr);
  }
  ```

Comment: I am using C++ Builder 11.3

Comment: @user3161924 Then it should be sufficient to create `_com_issue_error`

Comment: I did with a `throw("ComError");` because I couldn't include the header or it would complain about not matching the prototype.